# about cayley theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an abstract algebra book in which i saw there are two different theorem named as cayleys theorem.that are as follows
  1) if G is group then it is isomorphic into symmetric group S_G
  2) every group is isomorphic to a group of permutation.
   In first one author had not proved the onto condition and in second one author had proved the onto condition.
  what is the difference between these two theorem. anyone please help me for this.

Comment: What is the definition of the symmetric group $S_G$?  Generally, it is something like "the permutations on the elements of $G$".  If that's what it means, do you see how the two theorems are the same?

Comment: i know this definition. let A be finite set {1,2,...,n} then the group of all permutation of A is the symmetric group of n letters, denoted by S_n  having order n!. my question is these two theorem that i mentioned is different?  why?

Comment: My answer is that the two theorems are not fundamentally different.  They are "phrased" differently, though.

Comment: Cayley has many theorems...

Answer (score 1):

Cayley's theorem says

Every group $G$  is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A(S)$ where $A(S) $ is the set of all permutations of some set $S$. Since we are proving isomorphism to some subgroup of $A(S)$ no need to show onto.You can just try out the following mapping:

Take $S=G$ .For any $g\in G ,\tau_g $defined by $\tau_g(a)=ga$ is  a bijective mapping from $G $ to $G$(check that) .Now define $\phi:G\rightarrow A(G)$ by $\phi(g)=\tau_g$.Check yourself that no need to check onto .Hope that helps

Comment: I too think so but my teacher told me that according to first theorem  G isomorphic to subgroup of Sn and according to second one G is isomorphic to Sn.
 But i dont aggree with my teacher. i am confused.

Comment: Please dont get confused.In mathematics what you see is what you get

Comment: So , is Group G is isomorphic to Sn  ?  or according to both the theorems G is isomorphic to subgroup of Sn ?

Comment: If any group $G$ is isomorphic to $S_n$ then will not every group be non -commutative?

Comment: Thank you sir. so according to above theorems every group is isomorphic to subgroup of Sn  ?

Comment: Yes that follows from my proof right.

Comment: Sir, one more question is that if we serch on wikipedia then, then we saw two different articles for permuation group and symnetric group , is they are differe?  how ?

Comment: Sir,  please give reply to my last comment. i.e  is there is difference between permutation group and symmetric group.

Comment: Sorry for my belated reply.A permutation is a bijective mapping from a group $G$ to $G $.If we consider the set of all permutations of a group $G$ with composition operation then we get a permutation group.If $G$ is a finite set of $n$ elements then we get $S_n$